# C# how to have event off selecting a list view item

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have come across a stumbling block and I would like a small bit of help on this problem. The problem is that I have is that I have a list view and that works perfectly well. What I would like to do is when the user selects an item out of the column, then I would like it to enable two buttons.

[image: Test Audio Hightligh Choice]

The code is as follows

```
private void sourceList_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (sourceList.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        btnTest.Enabled = true;
        btnStop.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

I would be grateful for any help any advice I am given. I know that I may have gone down the wrong route and would be welcome any constructive criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please the listview has selectionChanged event try and use that instead like

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (sourceList.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        btnTest.Enabled = true;
        btnStop.Enabled = true;
    }
    }
```